# TFS Not Getting All Solution Files

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, tfsbuild

I am in the process of switching builds from 2013 xamls to tfs 2017. I have a project in which I am building some solution files, dbproj files, and sqlproj files. However, it is only working for one single solution file currently. The issue seems to be on my "GetSources" task in which I have everything mapped correctly - but I am only seeing the build go through the correct motions for the one working solution. I have my GetSources set to clean all build directories. Is there any reason as to why the GetSources task would not be working?

### Edit:

I have remoted on to our build server and the files for the one solution are downloaded. Files for two other solutions seem to be partially there. The workspace is also created. There are no errors or warnings in the logs when I run the build. I have this in the log for every solution I am trying to build:

> ##[command]tf vc workfold /map /workspace:ws_31_2 $path E:\agent /collection:http://server/tfs/DefaultCollection/ /loginType:OAuth
>   /login:.,******** /noprompt

it only fully "gets" one solution and part of two other solutions. None of the other solutions are even mentioned in the log except for some variation of that little snippet I added to account for their locations. I have tried debug mode and there were no red flags with that.

When I go to run the actual build, I get this error: 
`MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.` - because it is not getting the sources to start with.

Comment: Can you remote onto the build server and see what sources are downloaded? What workspaces are created?

Comment: So your problem is that the TFS does only find a single solution file? Does the build log show any errors/warnings? Maybe something is wrong with your path to the solution(s) - could you please provide that? Every tiny bit of information you can provide will help us to identify the problem. So it would be great if you could add the answers to the questions in the comments into your post by editing it. And Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Did you get any error on this, what's your build result for the single solution?Please share your log of get source step,  also [Enable Verbose Debug Mode](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/)  There are many possibilities such as permission, path too long , without the log info or error, it's hard to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Yes I have remoted on and the files for the one solution are downloaded. Files for two other solutions seem to be partially there. There are no errors in the logs when I run the build. Theres also no warnings. I have this in the log for every solution I am trying to build: `##[command]tf vc workfold /map /workspace:ws_31_2 $path E:\agent /collection:http://server/tfs/DefaultCollection/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt` it only fully "gets" one solution and part of two other solutions.None of the other solutions are even mentioned in the log except for that little snippet I added.

Comment: Can you share your folder structure of your solution and workspace settings for your build definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer has been found. It was a permissions error. Strange to me that there wouldn't have been an error reported in the logs, but I was able to change the permissions under security -> version control -> and inherited permissions from another folder for the folder that I was trying to access. Originally set to not inherit.

Comment: There's no errors produced because that could provide additional information about the layout of the repository, which somebody without read access should not be able to see.  That is to say, if there were an error like `cannot read secretfile.cs` then there's an information disclosure, and somebody without permissions could discover that `secretfile.cs` exists.  The TFS approach increases security, though admittedly making troubleshooting more difficult.